# CONCAT in SQL Server with a CASE WHEN troubleshooting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Demand Structure

```
select
    Model,
    concat('',max(case when ranking = 1 then [Demand Structure] end ),round(cast(max(case when ranking = 1 then [Demand Structure] as float/count([Demand Structure]))*100,2),'%') top1_Demand_Structure,
    concat('',max(case when ranking = 2 then [Demand Structure] end ),round(cast(max(case when ranking = 2 then [Demand Structure] as float/count([Demand Structure]))*100,2),'%') top2_Demand_Structure
    --into #demand_structure_temp

from
    (
        SELECT 
        Model,
        [Demand Structure],
        COUNT(1)Demand_Structure_count,
        row_number() OVER(partition by model ORDER BY count(1) DESC) as Ranking
        FROM [EDW].[sio].[TB_R_SURVEY_IN_OPERATION] 
        group by Model,[Demand Structure]
    )a
group by model
order by 1;
```

*round(cast(max(case when ranking = 1 then [Demand Structure] as float*
and
*round(cast(max(case when ranking = 2 then [Demand Structure] as float*

this two is highlighted by sql server as the error.

I plan to show the percentage result of the numbers returned in this query

example of the result:

```
|Top_1_Age|
-----------
|A 50%    |
|B 35%    |
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Both Line's 1 and 2 have more left parenthesis (`(`) than right (`)`).

Comment: `[Demand Structure] as float` doesn't make sense either; `AS float` isn't valid syntax for a `CASE` expression or `MAX` function.

Comment: You - or more likely someone else - will regret the consistent use of three-part names. The connection should determine the database to use for your table references. Otherwise, a change in database name or environment (like switching between dev, test, and production) requires a change to your code. Ordering by ordinal position is another bad habit. Develop good habits.

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are off.  In complicated expressions, I often try to align opening and closing parens so the logic is clear:

```
select
    Model,
    concat('',
           max(case when ranking = 1 then [Demand Structure] end),
           round(cast(max(case when ranking = 1 then [Demand Structure] end
                         ) as float
                     ) /
                     count([Demand Structure]) * 100, 2
                 ), '%') as top1_Demand_Structure,
           concat('',
                  max(case when ranking = 2 then [Demand Structure] end ),
                  round(cast(max(case when ranking = 2 then [Demand Structure]
                                ) as float
                            ) /
                            count([Demand Structure]) * 100, 2
                       ), '%') as top2_Demand_Structure
    --into #demand_structure_temp
```